# Phoenix: How can I set a environment variable?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a URL that will change depending on if I'm in dev or prod

in dev, it should be `http:localhost:3000`
in prod, it should be `https://www.foobar.com`

1. Where would I set the value of this environment variable?
2. How would I need to update this snippet in my controller so that it uses this environment variable?

```
    conn
      |> redirect(external: "http://localhost:3000")
```

Comment: Setting environment variables depends on what environment you’re in, eg Windiws, Linux, … Did you try searching for Elixir access environment variable it similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know this to be a compile-time variable, you can set it in `config/dev.exs`, `config/test.exs` and `config/prod.exs` (or set it in `config/config.exs` and override it in the environments when it's different).

If you need it to be configurable at runtime (i.e. something you can change after building a release with `mix release`), you can use `runtime.exs` for this instead.

There's an example that I believe is generated for you by default:

```
config :my_app, MyAppWeb.Endpoint,
  url: [host: "localhost"],
```

This type of nested config is accessed with, say,

```
 Application.get_env(:my_app, MyAppWeb.Endpoint, :url) |> Keyword.get(url)
# returns [host: "localhost"]
```

You can also do something like this:

```
config :my_app, external_support_site: 
"https://support.example.com"
```

In runtime.exs, if you really want to use an environment variable as the source of the URL, you may use `System.get_env("EXTERNAL_SUPPORT_SITE")` as the value that you assign to

```
config :my_app, :external_support_site, System.get_env("EXTERNAL_SUPPORT_SITE")
```

Which you can access in your example like this:

```
conn
|> redirect(external: Application.get_env(:my_app, :external_support_site, "https://some-default.example.com")
```